# how to show pickerview from another nib file to textfields inputview main storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, textfield

first of, I'm using xcode7.1 swift 2.

I have two nib/xib files, first is the main nib/xib and second one is pickview nib/viewcontroller file. How do I show the pickview nib/viewcontroller when textfield is tapped?

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var readableTextfield: Bool? = true

    textField.inputView = pickerViewCustom

    return readableTextfield!
}
```

pickerViewCustom is a UIPickerView from pickview nib/viewcontroller

What I'm trying to to make is when a user is filling up a form, a UIPickerview will popup and will select values from an array and display the selected value to the textview. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try set `inputView` when initializing UITextField, such as `viewDidLoad:`

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    textField.inputView = pickerViewCustom
    ...
}
```